# print unicode charcater to Rubymine console

Tags: ruby, rubymine, rubymine-7

So I want to print a hebrew character, unicode value of `\u{fb20}` into the Rubymine console, the common output where `hello world` would typically go if you were to just run `puts 'hello world'`.

The code I am trying to run is just `puts "\u{fb20}"`, nothing crazy.

Rubymine is set to default system encoding for both projectg and IDE levels, and I have tried setting the encoding to UTF-8 and UTF-16, but neither of these three setting will simply print this character correctly to the console.

I get `ï¬`  printed to the console at the moment, which is not the right character. The right character is `ﬠ`.

Comment: The UTF-8 representation of `ﬠ` is the three bytes `xEF`, `xAC`, `xA0`. Those three bytes interpreted as ISO-8859-1 are `ï¬ ` (where the last character is non-breaking space). So it looks like your IDE is using ISO-8859-1 (or Window-1252) when displaying the bytes from Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the character in ruby, and then printing it.

```
symbol = "\ufb20"
puts symbol.encode('utf-16')
```

And change Rubymine to be encoded in UTF-16